# Подсчитать сумму возвратов запроса

Tags: prolog

Мой запрос может вернуть различные значения. Мне бы хотелось найти их сумму. 
Пример

```
test(1).
test(2).
```

Какой запрос мне надо составить, чтобы получить ответ 3?

Comment: Пришлось подумать, как применить findall( Variable, Atom, ListVariable ) к моему примеру. Чтож, конкретно у меня это будет findall( X, test(X), L ), что вернет мне X=X и L=[1,2]. После чего осталось просуммировать элементы листа.  Спасибо, вопрос решен.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваш вопрос не совсем понятен. 
У вас есть база фактов и правил в виде одного предиката, которая может возвращать несколько решений и вам нужно найти сумму всех решений?

Если да, тогда можно взять встроенный предикат findall( Variable, Atom, ListVariable ), который их всех решений формирует список ( 3 аргумент). И уже потом вы сможете просуммировать весь список